# Why is my CFN IAM role failing with "Missing required field Action"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

My code clearly has an action. So I assume its a formatting error. I know it's a silly thing but I cant figure it out.

```
Resources:
  LambdaExecRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
       AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
         -
          Effect: Allow
           Principal:
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Service:
              - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Action needed to be at the same level as Principal.